# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7.27.+

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to create a new project in Android Studio, using Nougat 7.0.

But, as soon as I open the project I get the following Gradle error:

> Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7.27.+

I have tried some online solutions, but none of them have been working for me.

Below is the Module (app) build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "damo.com.testproject"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

What changes do I need to make to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Gradle DSL method not found: 'google()'

Set

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
```

Make sure added  **`google()`** in Your **`PROJECT LEVEL`** `build.gradle` section.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com/' }

    }
}
```

It will be better if you set **PROPER** version.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

**FYI**

Use **`implementation`** instead of **`compile`**. i.e

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

After that, **`Clean-Rebuild-Run`**.

Answer (score 0):

replace with this

com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1

Comment: Hi @nishant Now, when I try to sync gradle I get: _Gradle DSL method not found: 'google()'_

Comment: go to your project level gradle and add google() to allprojects dependencies

Comment: sorry not dependencies you need to add in allprojects repostories

Answer (score 0):

buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
change this to "27.0.0"
 and everything is going to be correct