error in my android studio gradle file or smthing
i cant run my code because of these errors can anyone help me to run them
i tried every method listed used chat gpt every thing but didnt worked
Build Kotlin Codes: failed At 01-09-2024 18:06 with 2 errors
its showing these errors
Download info
259 ms
:app:process Debug Resources 1 error
22 m
C:\Users\deban.gradle\caches\transforms-4\b176216d248277634dbcf2f5c8b55062\transformed\print-1.0.0\AndroidManifest.xml
C:\Users\deban.gradle\caches\transforms-4\acfb4c4f7bcb4c2dd5439c04313cdda4\transformed\lifecycle-process-2.6.2 AndroidManifest.xml

you need to add google repository   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50890149/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v7-27/50890280#50890280

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
